# Caching with UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

at the moment my program is constantly querying the same repositories repeatedly. I'm currently using UnitOfWork pattern to query my tables.

For example a query that is ran very often

```
var peopleCollection = UnitOfWork.PersonRepository.Get(x => x.Active);
```

To enhance my software to reduce repetitive task, may I ask what's the proper approach I should be taking to cache if I have a UnitOfWork pattern. I understand I can save the collection to a dictionary and call that dictionary whenever I want to use it. But the main issue with that approach is that I would have an outdated collection of people if another user were to save a new person.

Comment: Without caching you have not really an UOW. If you need the new data from the db than dispose the UOW instance and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that each situation requires a slightly different solution.

In general, the best solution is to use Decorator pattern to cache duplicate data calls, and ensure that the cache invalidates old data with an appropriate expiration policy.

For example, suppose that it won't bother your users to have Person data that is up to 60 seconds old. In that case, you could set the cache expiration during to 60 seconds.

Here is a sample for a generic cached item, which would be perfect for storing in a dictionary:

```
public class CachedItem<T>
{
    private readonly T _item; 
    private readonly DateTime _expirationTime;

    public CachedItem(T obj, TimeSpan cacheDuration)
    {
        _item = obj;
        _expirationTime = DateTime.Now.Add(cacheDuration);
    }

    public bool IsExpired { get { return DateTime.Now > _expirationTime; } }

    public T Item
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsExpired)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Expired Cached Items cannot be retrieved.");

            return _item;
        }
    }
}
```